# How can i represent this system as discrete markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, mathematical-modeling

Suppose that i have the following equations that represent the probabilistic lanchester model :

source : [probabilistic lanchester model](https://faculty.nps.edu/awashburn/Files/Notes/Lanchester.pdf)

$$  R'(t)  =-f(R(t),B(t)) $$  $$  B'(t)  =-g(R(t),B(t))  $$

$$ P ({(R ,B)→(R-1,B)})= f(R,B)\times\Delta \\ $$  $$ P ({(R ,B)→(R,B-1)})= g(R,B)\times\Delta  \\ $$  $$ P ({(R ,B)→(R,B)})= 1-f(R,B)\times\Delta -g(R,B)\times\Delta $$

Where :

$$  \Delta  : \text{is a very small time step.}  $$  $$ \\ R(t) 
   \text{ and } B(t)  \text{  represent effectifs evolution of the two
   opposite teams during the battle.}  $$

$$ (R ,B)→(R-1,B) $$ represents the event where the red team effectif decrease by 1 during battle. R and B are integers and at t=0 :  $$ R(t)=R(0)  \;and\;B(t)=B(0) $$

**My question is as follow :**

How this system could be modeled as a markov-chain ?

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: I guess that the probabilities of transition here aren't independant like classical markov-chains !